# TeXworks/pdflatex: why is the Computer Modern font rendered with low resolution?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, resolution

I'm currently on Windows/TeXworks/pdflatex and noticed that the Computer Modern font is low resolution. As you can see in the attached image, the Phv font renders correctly.

TeXworks v 0.6.5

MiKTeX 21.1

pdflatex/pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21

[image: Exhibit A]

and

[image: Comparison of Computer Modern and Phv on my TeXworks distribution.]

Comment: Install the cm-super package.

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are *not* “low resolution” fonts. They are bitmap fonts, which can't be enlarged arbitrarily. What you are after are vector/outline fonts. So `\usepackage{lmodern}` suffices.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!

Comment: I will add that using lmodern interfered with Helvetica in a way that I was unable to solve smoothly, and cm-super could not be installed via MiKTeX for whatever reason. I ended up installing TeXlive which finally resolved my problem: no need to load lmodern or to add extra code to force Helvetica for Sans Serif.